# What is the black box between my air filter housing and throttle body?

Tags: engine, air-intake

I recently purchased a 2001 Dodge Dakota 4.7L SOHC. I want to start working on my own vehicles more. But I have very little experience and this question reflects that.

[image: 2001 Dodge 4.7L SOHC V8]

Please correct me if I get anything wrong. But I believe I know what #1 and #3 are in my picture. #1 is the air filter housing. #3 is the throttle body.

What I have no idea about is #2. I can clearly see that it is in between my air filter and throttle body and is connected to both by hosing. **What is it and what does it do?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's basically a tuned box that serves to reduce intake noise.

Think of it as a muffler for the intake.

Comment: It can also provide a plenum area where the air can slow down and get better "organized" before it goes into the throttle body. It allows the air to get smoothed out a little bit and flow straighter. Not always, but it can be.

Comment: That makes sense. Just out of curiosity, does it affect performance at all?

Comment: On some vehicles it does.  Generally, however, they are not just a plain box like you have.  Look under the hood of your Lambo and you'll see something very different.